# Get possible values of field of type parameter set

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

How can I get all possible values of field of type parameter set from JavaScript?
I.e. I have entity Entity1 and it has field Field1, which is set of parameters(Param1,Param2,Param3).
How can I retrieve Param1, Param2 and Param3 from crm and pass it to select element of html?

Comment: Hi IDisposable, Maybe I'm the only one that didn't get it, but you have Entity1, that has a Field1 and you need to manipulate the values inside that Field1 in the same form, or you are working in Entity2 that has a lookup to Entity1 that contains that Field1? If is the first case MarioZG answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in CRM page context you can use

```js
Xrm.Page.getAttribute(attribute).getOptions();
```

If you don't have page context, have a  look at example in SDK (*SDK\SampleCode\JS\SOAPForJScript\SOAPForJScript\Scripts\SDK.MetaData.js*). You can find sample usage [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg594428.aspx).